# Is it possible to delete some rows in .x of purrr:::iwalk?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, purrr

I use **purrr:::iwalk** like this but it doesn't do what I want:

```
purrr:::iwalk(DGE_tables, ~ .x[-which(.x$column1 %in% VectorOfSpecificValues),])
```

DGE_tables is list of data-frames. In this all data-frames I want to delete rows which have a specific values in column1. The dataframes have the same structure.

Is it possible to do that with **purrr:::iwalk** ? Or there is a better way to do that?

**EDIT**: An example:

The list of dataframe:

```r
DGE_tables
```

```
# Display
$dataframe1
    column1   column2
1   to_delete    56
2   to_keep      45

$dataframe2
    column1   column2
1   to_delete    78
2   to_keep      27

...
```

So I want to delete rows which have $column1 = "to_delete". Like this:

```
# wanted result
$dataframe1
    column1   column2
1   to_keep      45

$dataframe2
    column1   column2
1   to_keep      27

...
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example

Comment: I will try to do that!

Comment: @akrun, is it more clear?

Comment: Why not simply `map(DGE_tables, ~filter(.x, column1 != "to_delete"))`

Comment: The `walk` functions are used for side effects—on their own, they don't return anything. They're useful for saving a file, then continuing to work with the data you use saved. You probably want a `map` function instead, which will do your operation, then pass the returned data frame to the next piped step

Comment: Actually, @camille, they return the original `.x` unmodified, it's returned invisibly.

Comment: @r2evans true, thanks. I can never explain them quite right. `walk` is definitely tricky. `map` is better suited to a case like this.

Comment: The fact that it returns anything is (I'm guessing) to allow it to work in the middle of a pipe, not just at the end. If that is not a consideration, then in my opinion anything that calls some "walk" like function in any prog lang may not safely assume any return value, as its intent is side-effect. \*shrug\*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be `filter`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(DGE_tables, ~ .x %>% 
                  filter(column1 != "to_delete"))
#[[1]]
#  column1 column2
#1 to_keep      45

#[[2]]
#  column1 column2
#1 to_keep      27
```

---

Or with `slice`

```
map(DGE_tables, ~ .x %>% 
                  slice(which(column1 != "to_delete")))
```

---

Or it can be done with `base R` as well

```
lapply(DGE_tables, subset, subset = column1 != "to_delete")
```

NOTE: The OP's dataset is a `list` of `data.frame` and needs a return output a `list` of `data.frame`s with subset of rows

and it wouldn't work with `keep` or `discard`

```
purrr::keep(DGE_tables, ~ .x[['column1']] == 'to keep')
```

> Error: Predicate functions must return a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not
>   a logical vector of length 2

#### data

```
DGE_tables <- list(structure(list(column1 = c("to_delete", "to_keep"), 
   column2 = c(56L, 
45L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2")), structure(list(
    column1 = c("to_delete", "to_keep"), column2 = c(78L, 27L
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2")))
```

Answer (score 3):

`purrr` has `keep()` and `discard()` just for this sort of thing:

```r
library(purrr)

l <- list(
    list(col1 = 'to keep', col2 = 1),
    list(col1 = 'to discard', col2 = 2)
)

purrr::keep(l, ~ .x[['col1']] == 'to keep')
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$col1
#> [1] "to keep"
#> 
#> [[1]]$col2
#> [1] 1
purrr::discard(l, ~ .x[['col1']] == 'to discard')
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$col1
#> [1] "to keep"
#> 
#> [[1]]$col2
#> [1] 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things at work here. Since I don't have your data (yet?), I'll make my own, rather crudely:

```r
dge <- list(mtcars[1:5,], mtcars[1:5,])
```

Some problems:

1. By definition, `purrr::walk` and `purrr::iwalk` return the original frame `.x`, *regardless of what you do in the function block*. As an example, see this:

   ```r
   (purrr::iwalk(dge, ~ return(NULL)))
   # [[1]]
   #                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
   # Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
   # Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
   # Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
   # Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
   # Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
   # [[2]]
   #                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
   # Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
   # Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
   # Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
   # Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
   # Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
   ```

   (If you do just `purrr::iwalk(dge, ...)` without the surrounding parens, you won't see anything because the default is to return the return value *invisibly*. The parens force it to be visible.)

   So the hard point here is that your example of just filtering within the `iwalk` will not work. For that, you probably want `purrr::imap`. (If you are doing more and the small example in your question was a shorter snippet of more code, then you are probably still good with `iwalk`.)
2. I tend to prefer to *not* use `which` in blocks like that, as the absence with negation of `which` can be problematic (negative empty-vector does not do "nothing"). Instead, I suggest using logical vectors, and not integer vectors.

   Examples: I'll try a stupid conditional of `1 %in% 2`, which should obviously find nothing (and with your negation, return all rows):

   ```r
   dge[[1]][ -which(1 %in% 2), ]
   #  [1] mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
   # <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
   ```

   Using a logical vector instead (and `!` instead of `-`) returns what we expect (i.e., all rows):

   ```r
   dge[[1]][ !(1 %in% 2), ]
   #                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
   # Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
   # Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
   # Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
   # Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
   # Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
   ```